# Scope not updating in link directive on ng-submit

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, submit

I can't get the scope object to update on submit. The submit function is called, but the console shows the object does not update. I have tried most similar problem-solutions I have found.

The directive (inside index.html):

```
<div d-header-login class="header-login"></div>
```

The directive HTML:

```
<div class="container_header-login">
    <div data-ng-if="!login.opLogin">
        <form ng-submit="submit()">
            <input type="text" ng-model="username" placeholder="username/email" />
            <input type="text" ng-model="scope.password" placeholder="password" />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login"/>
        </form>
        <a href="#">Register</a>            
        <a href="#">Forgot password</a> 
    </div>
    <div data-ng-if="login.opLogin">
        <!--{{login.opLogin}}-->
        Logged in as
    </div>
</div>
```

The directive js

```
var mHeaderLogin = angular.module('app.directives.mHeaderLogin', ['mMain'])// mMain-dependent due to factory call
.directive('dHeaderLogin', fHeaderLogin);
function fHeaderLogin() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        //replace: true,
        scope: {
            username: '='
        }, //isolate scope
        templateUrl: 'app/directives/header-Login/header-Login.html',
        controller: function ($scope, simpleFactory) {
            $scope.users = simpleFactory.getUsers();
            $scope.username = "test";
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.login = { opLogin: false };
            scope.submit = function () {
                console.log(scope.username);
                console.log("fSubmit");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The log will show "test"; not what I wrote in the input box

Comment: can you put your code is jsfiddle or some thing like that

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do this with AngularJS. I tried now but it does not work.